# M1 Mac上のVSCodeで"IntelliSenseModeが変更されました"メッセージが毎回出てしまうのを止めたい

Tags: c++, macos, vscode

M1 Macにて、VSCodeでワークスペースを新規作成したディレクトリに対し.vscodeディレクトリごとコピーし、そのディレクトリを開くコマンドをaliasを作って実行しています。
VSCode起動時（上記で新規作成したディレクトリを開いた時）にはメッセージが出ませんが、
.cppファイルを開いた際に、以下メッセージが毎回表示されてしまいます。
都合上clangではなくgccを用いたいのですが（<bits/stdc++.h>をインクルードしたいので）、毎回下記メッセージが出てしまい非常に煩わしい為改善したく、どなたか知見ないでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
[2023/10/8 13:09:50] C++ ソース ファイルで、コンパイラの引数と compilerPath のクエリに基づいて、IntelliSenseMode が "macos-gcc-arm64" から "macos-clang-arm64" に変更されました: "/usr/bin/gcc"
[2023/10/8 13:09:50] C ソース ファイルで、コンパイラの引数と compilerPath のクエリに基づいて、IntelliSenseMode が "macos-gcc-arm64" から "macos-clang-arm64" に変更されました: "/usr/bin/gcc"
```

**.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "macos-gcc-arm64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "lldb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
~省略~
```

**ターミナルでの実行結果**

```
$ which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
（g++は/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13へのシンボリックリンクです）
```

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[C++の競プロ環境を作る M1 Mac(Big Sur)](https://qiita.com/hayapo/items/21032ae726ed15b11563), [【M1以降の Mac, Windows対応】Visual Studio CodeでC/C++を実行する環境を構築する方法](https://www.edp-ken.com/post-8/) 最初の記事のように compilerPath(とかincludePath)に明示的に g++ や関連フォルダを指定すれば良いのでは？

Comment: 共有ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

お騒がせしてすみません、自己解決しました。

1. `<bits/stdc++.h>` をインクルードできる
2. cppファイルを開く度に表示される、「IntelliSenseModeが変更されました」メッセージを表示させないこと

clangでもgccでもどちらでもいいので、とにかく上記２つの要件を満たせればよかったので、
IntelliSenseModeをmacos-clang-arm64に設定し、以下リンクのように設定したところ所望の動作が実現できました。

[clang で bits/stdc++.h を使う](https://qiita.com/y3km21/items/7cdf6fec8c3ff59db4bb)

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` は gcc の拡張機能なので無理やり clang で使ってもいいことないですよ。これは競技プログラミング界隈固有の悪癖なのでマネしないほうが吉。オイラの後輩君が実用に供するコードでこれ書いてたらぶっ飛ばします。